# Header button appears on the hamburger menu

Tags: css

I have a header button which looks like this

[image]

here is the code:

```
.button {
        width: 148px !important;
        min-height: 40px !important;
        font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif !important;
        font-weight: 500 !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        background: transparent !important;
        margin-bottom: 60px !important;
        backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    }
```

and then I have a hamburger menu like this:

[image]

here is the code:

```
<div className={styles.overlay}>
                <div className={styles.content}>
                                    <span className={styles.openedArrow2}></span>
                                    <h1 onClick={onClick2}>{'Main Menu'}</h1>
                                    {pagination && (
                                        <>
                                            <span className={styles.pagination}>.</span>
                                            <h2 onClick={onClick3}>Services</h2>
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </>
                        )}
                        <div onClick={onClick} className={styles.close}></div>
                    </div>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(18, 34, 45, 0.65);
}

.content{
    position: absolute;
    width:294px;
    height: 640px;
    background: rgb(62,75,83, 0.88);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    padding: 24px 20px 0 42px;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    line-height: 2;

}
```

[image]

When I open the menu, it looks like this:

When I comment the backdrop-filter: blur(12px), it works fine but I need the button to be blurred. How to fix this?

Comment: If you are going to ask a CSS and HTML question, you need to show the generated CSS and HTML and not whatever other language that is that only clutters things up and makes us wonder what is going on. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Increase the z-index of your overlay clas

```
z-index:9999999;
```

Comment: It didn't work! Now the button even covers the menu content.

Comment: Dear @Majid Ali shah, although your answer didn't work, I found the answer. Just added z-index:-1 to the button and it worked. Thank you!